# How to create a WordPress PAGE in another folder?

Tags: php, posts, redirect, urls

I have a URL Shortening script running on the homepage while there is a WordPress installation on another folder named blog. So that would look like this https://homepage.com/blog

The problem is that I need to be able to create "PAGES" for terms, about, FAQ, private policy, etc. Whenever a page is created in WordPress for let's say "terms" then a page like this is created: https://homepage.com/blog/terms

What the URL really should be is https://homepage.com/page/terms. The reasoning is because the homepage's script has it's own links pointing to it's own pages and blog.

So far since I have successfully managed to create the WordPress blog in https://homepage.com/blog then this overwrites the links in the homepage's own blog so that they point to the actual WordPress blog.

So I am thinking that if that is possible then it should be possible to have the links in the homepage point to "Pages", which I want to be "Pages" that were actually created in WordPress.

In other words, how can I create, move, recreate, or duplicate **https://homepage.com/blog/terms** which I actually want to be located at **https://homepage.com/page/terms** so that the homepage links can point to that instead?

I only have limited knowledge on php scripts and none as far as database tables are concerned. If I could create a php file for this then that would be so greatly appreciated.

I have a child-theme for the WordPress installation that php files can be placed in. The homepage's script is all in php and MySQL.

Comment: So to clairfy: - You have a website in the root folder of your domain - You have a WordPress installation in the 'blog' folder - You would like to be able to create pages that reside within a 'pages' type folder What is the main website built on? Can you not create the pages within the main website and assign them a parent page called 'pages' which will give you the URL structure that you need? Could you create a folder called 'pages' and install WordPress in there like you have done for the blog?

Comment: It sounds like your problem stems from the fact that you installed WordPress in a specific subfolder, and it can't create URLs outside of that folder without a lot of messy workarounds. Have you considered installing WordPress in your root folder? You can still have actual subfolders on your site that run other code, and WP has quite a bit of URL shortening magic built in. For example, if you add a page at `http://example.com/toplevel/secondlevel/thirdlevel` you can get there by typing in `example.com/thirdlevel`.

Comment: Or, if you just want to move your entire WP install from `/blog/` to `/page/` there are Database Migration plugins available that can help you move everything.

Comment: And, if you just avoided installing WP in the root folder because you want to run custom PHP and MySQL, you can install WP in the root and then set up a `front-page.php` template with whatever custom code you need, thus bringing it "into WordPress" but running custom code.

Comment: Hi @Ben, Yes I have thought of creating a folder called 'pages' and installing WordPress in there. That probably is the easiest solution I would think. I suppose it's ok to have an another entire WordPress installed in another folder, just for 5 pages. Yes I can create pages in the main website, but it has it's own layout and structure, however I was wanting to keep the WordPress theme's structure. It looks like this answer was deleted, so hope you can see this comment.

Comment: @WebElaine What how exactly would one set up a front-page.php template? I can't imagine powering a URL shortening script simultaneously with a WP Installation.

Comment: @Merc Striebeck It is overkill to install WP but it sounds like it might be *easier* for you in this scenario. You should be able to create custom page templates on your existing  site though but this is dependant on theme, etc which is hard to determine on this question

Comment: @Ben H Would creating a custom page template allow for the page to be placed in any location such as the root domain in this case?

Comment: Sounds like your options are: maintain 2 separate WordPress installations so you can have the URLs you want, or set up 1 install in the root folder, which would allow you to then create custom post types in any subfolders you like. There are redirection plugins available for WP, so that might also be easier to use than your own custom script, and if redirection is your only need for the homepage you wouldn't even have to set up any templates.

Comment: Templates don't let you put pages anywhere, they're just files that contain code to run at whatever URL they are applied to. So, if you have things to display on your homepage you can place that markup there; if you have other code you want to run like your redirects, you can also place that PHP there and it will run.

Comment: @WebElaine those are very good suggestions, but I don't think running both a URL shortening script and a WP script on the same root domain would work out that great, or maybe it would I don't know. I thought maybe I could just change the links pointing from the URL shortening script, which is on the homepage, to the WP pages, but again, I don't understand the PHP driving the links on the shortener script. Those links are only created when I actually make a page using that script, but I don't understand the script. I'm ignorant when it comes to php, and God forbid databases.

Comment: @Ben H Well I decided to just go the install a WordPress into a directory named page route. It works just fine and I have basically unlimited storage and it doesn’t affect speed or anything so I’m pretty happy about that. I just needed those links on the front page to direct to URLs that are on there. Thanks for the suggestions, it’s greatly appreciated.